# Custom angular filter

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm getting some JSON data from a WordPress site to my ionic app, I'm filtering the data receipts and it works successfully, for example I'm getting the "price" field:

```
<label class="item item-input"> <input type="text" size="17" placeholder="Prix Min" ng-model="prixmin" ng-change="showSelectValue(prixmin)"> </label>

<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right" ng-repeat="post in recent_posts | filter:{ custom_fields: { trav_accommodation_avg_price:prixmin}}">
```

My problem is that I don't want to get posts with exactly the value of the price but I want to get posts they have values greater than this value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom filter that takes the price (here `prixmin`) as input and gives you the only items having price more than that. Something like:

```
.filter("priceGreaterThan", function() {
  return function(arr, price) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
      return Number(obj.custom_fields.trav_accommodation_avg_price) > Number(price)
    }
  })
})
```

And, use it in your `ng-repeat` like,

```
ng-repeat="post in recent_posts | priceGreaterThan: prixmin"
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work , when I replaced the > with the equal mark == , it works fine like the simple filter (I got the price I entred ) but with the 'greater than' mark I can't filter .

Comment: @MedAnis probably because either one or both price values that we are comparing are strings and not numbers.. try having them surrounded with `Number(...)` like `Number(price)` and same for the other

Comment: yes exactly , it was about the number type , thank you for the help , it works now .